# How to run Express and Mongo using docker-compose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, docker, docker-compose

How to run Express and MongoDB using docker-compose?

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
    express:
         image: node:7.7.2-alpine
         container_name: express-container
         ports:
            - 3000:3000
         volumes:
            - .:/application/
            - /application/node_modules
         links:
            - mongodb
         command: npm start

    mongodb:
        image: mongo:3.4.4
        container_name: mongo-container
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
```

After run `docker-compose up` mongo looks work fine:

```
mongo-container | 2017-07-06T22:17:53.939+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

But express give me this:

```
express-container | npm info it worked if it ends with ok
express-container | npm info using npm@4.1.2
express-container | npm info using node@v7.7.2
express-container | npm ERR! Linux 4.9.27-moby
express-container | npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
express-container | npm ERR! node v7.7.2
express-container | npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
express-container | npm ERR! path /package.json
express-container | npm ERR! code ENOENT
express-container | npm ERR! errno -2
express-container | npm ERR! syscall open
express-container |
express-container | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/package.json'
express-container | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/package.json'
express-container | npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
express-container | npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
express-container | npm ERR! enoent
express-container |
express-container | npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
express-container | npm ERR!     /npm-debug.log
express-container exited with code 254
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my compose file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lack to specify the WORKDIR. As this in Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /application
```

Or just in docker-compose.yml in the corresponding service:

```
working_dir: /application
```

npm will look there for the package.json file.

Comment: Not working, still same problem but with another path, now: npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/application/package.json'

Comment: Where is located your package.json file?

Comment: Changing image: node:7.7.2-alpine to biuld: . and everything works fine, of course add working_dir: /application too, thanks